# unwanted ~5 sec delay XHR request on chrome 42

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

Sometimes my XHR request are pending for 5 sec before they start, this problem only happen on chrome 42 (it's fine on canary 45 and firefox)

Trace show that they are stuck in `"URLRequest:ResponseStarted"`

if I `abort()` the request and restart a new one with the same parameters it's starting instantly as usual.

the first request always work fine.

```js
function generateLoader(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.send(null);
    return xhr;
}

function reproduceBug(url) {
  var xhr = generateLoader(url);
  // this is my poor attempt to bypass the delay :
  var stuckInPending = setTimeout(function() {
      console.warn('request appears to be stuck, re-trying');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = undefined;
      xhr.abort();
      xhr = generateLoader(url);
  }, 250);

  // if the onreadystatechange begins before the timeout, clear it.
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      clearTimeout(stuckInPending);
      this.onreadystatechange = undefined;
  };
}
```

If you call `reproduceBug('/path/to/data')` 2 consecutive times you will the warning the 2nd time.

What am I missing ?

[image: screenshot of chrome trace]

Comment: Hmm, I'm on Chrome 42, and obviously, the warnings appear because the timeout is too short, but I don't think we can't really test this with this code. I tried running two requests consecutively (changing the timeout to `5000` results in two successful requests, at least for StackOverflow). I also ran 50 requests inside a loop, with a timeout of `5000` as well, and no delay happened. Couldn't this be an issue with your server somehow?

Comment: this timeout is from the `.send()` and the first `.onreadystatechange`, so i believe 250 ms is already pretty generous.
Anyway, I don't have any issue on other navigators and was able to reproduce the bug on other servers.
Maybe it's from an add-on... [firefox and chrome timeline side by side](http://i.imgur.com/gHUoJi8.png)